# loop through multi dimensional array jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have an returned data from an php function as the following :

```
data[0]
     [0]
       <table>
        ....
       </table>
     [1]
       <table>
        ....
       </table>
       .
       .
       .etc
 data[1]
```

how can i loop through this array by javascript !

Comment: what have you tried? please explain the mix of array and html, what exactly is the data type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be possible to have a nested [jQuery foreach function.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) { 
  //this is each data... data[0], data[1]... etc, the value being value and the index being key.
  $.each(key, function(innerKey, innerValue){
    //this is where your tables are. innerKey being the index innerValue being the value.
    <table>
    ...
    </table>
  });
});
```